# Override Apple Siri remote Menu Button Default behavior

Tags: objective-c, tvos

According to Apple's [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/remote-and-interaction/), pressing the menu button on tvOS should return you to the previous menu, until you're at the top menu at which point it should return you to the OS menus. My question is, how do I prevent the default behavior of the menu button and stop it from returning to the OS menus, but then reactivate it when the user is at the top menu of my app?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can register a `tapGestureRecognizer` and set `allowedPressTypes = UIPressTypeMenu` code like so:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
tapGestureRec.allowedPressTypes = @[@(UIPressTypeMenu)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRec];
```

Then whenever the Siri remotes menu button is pressed your `handleTap` method will be called, allowing you to add any custom logic you need. Just be aware that blocking the menu button from suspending your application on the root view controller can be a cause for App Store rejection.

You can get more information about detecting gestures [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH16-SW1) and about pressTypes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPress_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIPressType).

Comment: Does the simple act of adding it to the view's recognized gestures stop it from performing its default behavior?

Comment: Yes, that what I am using in my, it will call your provided selector when ever MenuButton will be pressed so now its up to you what you are doing with that...

Comment: I have added tapgesture on AVPLayerViewController but menu button gesture not call in tvos.

Answer (score 6):

Swift version of @C_X's answer, which worked for me.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
tapGesture.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Menu.rawValue)]
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Swift 3 version:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyClass.handleMenuPress(_:)))
tapGesture.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.menu.rawValue)]
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Comment: I am working on Apple Tv application. This app is based on play video. My requirement is that when user pause the video and press the menu button, the video play continuous. I want on video pause state that the user press the menu button then the screen redirect to a previous screen without play video.

Comment: In your _handleTap_ function, you should be able to pop the current VC from the stack.

Comment: Nice, succinct solution. Added syntax for Swift 3.

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is something you get for free by using `UINavigationController`.

More generally, a container view controller can use the `-gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` delegate method to allow or prevent a menu button tap gesture recognizer from beginning based on whether it's at the root level of nesting or not.  When the shared `UIApplication` instance receives an unhandled menu button press, it will inform the system, which will cause the app to be sent to the background.

Comment: The cleanest solution I have found so far. Works nicely!